# Need to write a bash script that will grab every video file in a folder and apply a ffmpeg operation to them

Tags: linux, bash

Essentially a batch application of the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "01.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "test.mkv"
```

My hope would be to simply run this in a directory and have all the newly fixed files with the old file names and the old files appended with "old_" or something similar. I know next to nothing about bash, but have some experience with c++ and java, so terminology is not an issue, I just have never looked at bash before. Thanks!

EDIT: To be clear, I'd like the new file to be "01.mkv" and the old file to be renamed to "old_01.mkv". My research has told me this will probably require gawk, but I know even less about that than I do bash.

EDIT2: I realize I should have provided what I had been able to put together so far on my own.

```
#!/bin/bash
    for i in $( ls ); do
        ffmpeg -i $i -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy $i
    done
```

Comment: I suggest you start learning about `bash` by investigating the `for` statement.

Comment: I edited above. What I have theoretically works, I guess what I am not understanding is how to change the file names? Is it as easy as simple saying something like `$i = old_$i`? Or would I use command lines like in a normal terminal? like `for (blah blah) cp $i old_$i`. I've also seen people talking about gawk in related questions, but that seems overly complex for what I'm doing. Regardless, I can't seem to get the above ideas to work either, unless maybe I'm just doing them wrong

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after messing around with this for a few hours after getting a lucky Google search result I hadn't seen before, I finally figured this out. This is the answer, in case anyone else comes along and needs to do something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mkv;
    do
        oldFile=old_"$file"
        mv "$file" "$oldFile"
        ffmpeg -i "$oldFile" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -c:s copy "$file"
    done
```